# zclip not working?

Tags: jquery, copy, flash, zclip

im including the script:

```
<script src="http://www.cv-library.co.uk/js/zclip.js"></script>
```

and then calling it with:

```
$('a#adminBTBlue').zclip({
    path:'/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:$('#copypath').text(),
});
```

with HTML:

```
    <div id="copypath">im some text</div>
    <a href="" class="adminBTBlue" id="adminBTBlue">Copy</a>
```

but i get :
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'zclip'

Ive checked the path to the script and it works... confused?

Answer (score 1):

See this : **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/BXeTZ/1/)**

```
$("a#adminBTBlu").on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}).zclip({
   path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
   copy: function () {
       return $('#copypath').text();
   }
});
```

May be something wrong with the file you are trying..

Comment: i now get - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' - .. Im using jquery from google: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: are you including library reference multiple times..?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery included?
Do you get other errors?

I made a jsFiddle to test, but nothing got copied to my clipboard, but I don't get any errors either.

http://jsfiddle.net/UU8MZ/

Your code:

```
$('a#adminBTBlue').zclip({
    path:'http://www.cv-library.co.uk/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:$('#copypath').text(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery 1.8.3 - zClip seems not to be compatible with the jQuery 2.0 API yet, which was introduced with jQuery 1.9.